# UICollectionView set a viewForHeaderInSection similar to UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3, uicollectionview

To see what I mean exactly you can visit App Store and open any app. Inside the AppPage you will see Segmented Button (Details, Reviews, and Related). When you scroll down AppPage this Segmented Button stays the top of the page. So how do implement such sections or maybe it is not a section at all.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is called sticky header, and yes its available in tableview. But you should remember that this header sticks only to its responsible section, so if you have i.e. 2 sections, header will stays at the top of screen untill you'll reach end of this sections and if you provide header for section2 now this one will sticks to the top, and previous one will be gone. In this case (appstore) you have probably 1 section with a header attached to it and couple cells. They're plenty of tuts how to do this so you should be good to go.